# Make [kv] a synonym of [kivy-language]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

[kivy-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kivy-language) is a relatively new tag with a tag info available. It's used in [kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kivy). [kv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kv) has ~10 questions, no info and could be misused with [logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logstash) as it was with two or three questions because of [filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html).

[kivy-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kivy-language) is officially named [Kv language](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html) probably because `.kv` suffix and a relationship with `kivy` (-> `kv`, even Kivy logo seems to have those two characters in it), therefore people from kivy may use it because it's: **1)** language's original name **2)** shorter to write; this way [kivy-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kivy-language) related questions are divided into [kv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kv) and [kivy-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kivy-language) tags.

Comment: Why not just editing those questions?

Comment: @Braiam gladly, but there's still someone who uses the tag, see the latest question("yesterday"). `kv` is used term for the lang itself or in the meaning of present `.kv` file in app folder which basically points to usage of the Kv lang itself. As the tag is already usable, editing the questions would fix it in the short run, not in the long run. As `1 rep` user I thought the tags work the same way as e.g. tumblr or instagram - random words someone looks for. I think I'm not alone that was confused in the beginning. This confusion may lead to using the `kv` tag even if it'd have 0 questions.

Comment: Once the kv tag has 0 questions and 00:00 UTC passes, nobody under 1.5k rep can (re)create the tag. Tags that has no questions associated aren't suggested, nor cannot be used. Don't worry, they will find the kivy-language tag (or whatever).